# How to add list of SonataUserBundle Users to admin dashboard (SonataAdminBundle)?

Tags: symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

### How to add Users to admin dashboard?

My app:

- Symfony 2.0.16
- FOSUserBundle 1.2.x
- SonataAdminBundle
- SonataMediaBundle
- SonataPageBundle
- SonataUserBundle

I've followed the instructions in sonata-project.org and I get no errors, but my admin dashboard is empty! I would like to manage my Users and Groups.

I don't know if thats relevant but Sonata is added in kernel as:

> new SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle')

How to add CRUD for User's and Groups to my admin dashboard?

If you want to see my config, just tell me which part. I did not post all my configs, becouse there are alot of lines of code and I wanted to keep this question clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the docs in many parts are outdated or with typo's.

removeing groups

```
sonata_admin:
    dashbpard:
        groups:
            default: ~
```

from config did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This config works well for me

```
    sonata_admin:
...
        dashboard:

...
            groups:
...    
                user:
                    label: Users management
                    items:
                        - sonata.user.admin.user
                        - sonata.user.admin.group
```

Comment: this config gives me : An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("unable to find the route `sonata.user.admin.user.manage`") in SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig at line 216.